# Load dynamic optgroup items into html select

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a modal form with two select boxes with the same `current_models` class.

```
<div class="row">      
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Model</label>
         <select class='form-control' id='left_model_id' name='left_model_id'>
            <div id="left_model" class="current_models"></div>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Model</label>
         <select class='form-control' id='right_model_id' name='right_model_id'>
            <div id="right_model" class="current_models"></div>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Each select needs to have it's own `id`, but they are loading the same `select` options into groups like this:

```
$('.current_models').load('ajax_get_models_man_group.php');
```

Here's my `ajax_get_models_man_group.php` page:

```
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = new User();
if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
Redirect::to('login.php');
}


$models = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT man.id AS man_id, man.man AS man, models.name AS model, models.id AS model_id FROM hearing_aid_models models LEFT JOIN hearing_aid_man man ON man.id = models.man_id WHERE models.currently_fitting = 'Y' AND company_id = '" . $user->data()->company_id . "' ORDER BY man ASC");


if ($models->error()) {
    echo 'Error occurred.'; 
} else {

$currentGroup = null;
foreach( $models->results() as $result ) {
    // start a new optgroup
    if( $currentGroup == null || $result->man_id != $currentGroup ) {
        // end the previous group
        if( $currentGroup != null ) {
            echo "</optgroup\n>";
        }

        // start a new group
        echo "<optgroup data-id='{$result->man_id}' label='{$result->man}'>\n";

        $currentGroup = $result->man_id;
    }

    echo "<option value='{$result->model_id}'>{$result->model}</option>\n";
}

// end the last opt group
if( $currentGroup != null ) echo "</optgroup>\n";

    }
?>
```

The problem is that the values do not load into the select `div`s!

Here's my ajax source code results:

```
<optgroup data-id='1' label='Audibel'>
<option value='95'>Start 7 Wireless</option>
<option value='96'>Start 7</option>
<option value='99'>A3i Platinum</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup data-id='16' label='Phonak'>
<option value='98'>Naida Q70</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup data-id='2' label='Starkey'>
<option value='100'>S Series i30</option>
<option value='81'>3 Series I 70</option>
<option value='82'>3 Series I 90</option>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: Please post your markup and the result of the ajax

Comment: I added the ajax results.  What else can I provide to help?  Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me you're loading via ajax inside the wrong div. I'll post an answer to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Get rid of divs inside select tags**

```
<div class="row">      
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Model</label>
         <select class='form-control current_models' id='left_model_id' name='left_model_id'>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Model</label>
         <select class='form-control current_models' id='right_model_id' name='right_model_id'>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**2) load ajax inside the right div**

```
$('.current_models').load('ajax_get_models_man_group.php');
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I overlooked this possibility!  For some reason, I assumed .load had to work with spans or divs only.  I'm learning about jquery now.  I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.